# org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 ignoring Gradle toolchain

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

It looks like the spring-boot-gradle-plugin is ignoring my Java Toolchain declaration in my build.gradle file.  I'm not sure why though.

```
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.0.0
      > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6
' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

My build.gradle looks like the following:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "3.3.1"
}

group = 'dev'
version = '0.0.2-SNAPSHOT'
def app = "application-v2"

repositories {
    maven{
        url "${System.getenv("ARTIFACT_REPO")}".toString()
        name 'artifacts'
        credentials{
            username = System.getenv("GIT_DEV")
            password = System.getenv("GIT_TOKEN")
        }
    }
}

jib{
    from{
        image = 'gcr.io/distroless/java17:latest'
    }
    to{
        auth{
            username= System.getenv("KUBE_USER")
            password= System.getenv("KUBE_TOKEN")
        }
        image = "${System.getenv("IMG_REPO")}/dev/application-v2".toString()

    }
    container{
        environment = ["SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_LABEL": System.getenv("BRANCH_NAME")]
        jvmFlags = ["-Ddd.service.name=esg-apps-imaging-v2"
                    ,"-Ddd.trace.span.tags=env:${System.getenv("BRANCH_NAME")}".toString()]
        ports = ["8443"]
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.apache.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '4.0.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.70'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-crypto', version: '5.7.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.13.4.1'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-runtime-attach:3.4.8'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '5.3.20'
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-yaml:4.0.7'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: "*.jar")
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0359'
    implementation group: 'javax.jws', name: 'javax.jws-api', version: '1.1'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.soap', name: 'javax.xml.soap-api', version: '1.4.0'
    implementation group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.14'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-groovy:1.6.14'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.11.0'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.5'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.5'
    testImplementation platform(group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-bom', version: '2.4-M1-groovy-4.0')
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core"
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-junit4"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

java{
    toolchain{
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        showStackTraces = true
        exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
    }
}
```

If anyone could provide some guidance on what I might be doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.  One small disclaimer: if I remove the plugin and simply define the version tags in my build.gradle everything compiles just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your system java version is 11 (you can check this using "java --version" command), so in my opinion you have 2 options.

1. install java 17 on your system (and check again "java --version") and run gradle build or
2. download jdk 17 and while running gradle build use that as command line argument.
   example - if suppose you download jdk 17 in the 'D:\jdk-17' directory then your command line becomes -

gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home=D:\jdk-17 clean build

Note: Also it might require gradle version 6.7.1 or higher.

Comment: I'm running Gradle 7.6 currently which is what's perplexing.  This is a problem on a local system and in the cloud.

Comment: Did you try running build using jdk 17?

Comment: As I understand it, that is what the java tool chain is supposed to accomplish correct?  I'll reiterate that if i remove the plugin and simply define the version of the spring boot dependencies I need explicitly then the whole thing works fine.

Comment: You can use the com.github.rmee.jdk-bootstrap plugin rather than the gradle java toolchain: